# Wordpress submenu : children in ul

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I need some help to create a submenu with Wordpress.
For that I tried to use **wp_get_nav_menu_items** Wordpress's function.

I wrote this PHP function. All works fine but my second level is as the same level as my first level :

```
<?php

function fp_menu($menu) {
    global $post;

    $last = '';
    $args = array(
        'order'                  => 'ASC',
        'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
        'post_type'              => 'nav_menu_item',
        'post_status'            => 'publish',
        'output'                 => ARRAY_A,
        'output_key'             => 'menu_order',
        'nopaging'               => true,
        'update_post_term_cache' => false 
    );

    $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu, $args );
    if ($items != '') {
        $nav = '';
        for ($i=0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
            if ($items[$i]->object_id == $post->ID) {
                $activeClass = 'active';} else {$activeClass = '';
            }
            if ($items[$i]->type !== 'custom') {
                $nav.= '<li class="'.$activeClass.'"><a href="'.get_permalink($items[$i]->object_id).'" target="'.$items[$i]->target.'">'.$items[$i]->title.'</a></li>';
            } else {
                $nav.= '<li><a href="'.$items[$i]->url.'" target="'.$items[$i]->target.'">'.$items[$i]->title.'</a></li>';
            }
        }

        return '<ul>'.$nav.'</ul>';
    }
}
```

In html :

```
<?php echo fp_menu('main_menu'); ?>
```

Unfortunately all my `li` are in the same level, how can I put my submenu items in `ul > li`

A structure like this :

```
<nav class="header--nav">
    <ul class="header--menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item level 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item level 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item level 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item level 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Well you are not outputting anything anywhere that could create a second level (no additional `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags) - so what are you expecting? And why are you trying to build this yourself, instead of using WP's Walker_Nav_Menu class or something like that?

Comment: @CBroe What is Walker_Nav_Menu class ? And how this work ?

Answer (score 0):

### Do you really need it?

Wordpress has built-in functions for basic templating stuff like this, namely `wp_nav_menu()` in this case. If you want to roll your own walker to customize the way the nav is rendered, you should read up on [the docs for wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) as it is extensively discussed there.

### If you really want to roll your own from scratch

The easiest way, I would suggest is separating your HTML building logic into a separate function that you can call recursively if the given navigation item happens to be a submenu. Also, since uncontrolled recursion is pretty evil, you should add a limit to your function to avoid infinite loops and determine the maximum depth of your nav. Building on where you left off, something along the lines of:

```
function fp_menu($menu) {
    global $post;

    $last = '';
    $args = array(
        'order'                  => 'ASC',
        'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
        'post_type'              => 'nav_menu_item',
        'post_status'            => 'publish',
        'output'                 => ARRAY_A,
        'output_key'             => 'menu_order',
        'nopaging'               => true,
        'update_post_term_cache' => false );

    $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu, $args );

    return build_menu($items, $post, 2);
}

function build_menu($items, $currentPage, $depth) {
    if($items != '') {
        $nav = '';
        for ($i=0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
            // add active class if applicable
            if ($items[$i]->object_id == $post->ID) {
                $activeClass = 'active';
            } else {
                $activeClass = '';
            }
            // trigger recursion if submenu
            if (($depth !== 0) && $items[$i]->children /*or whatever you call it in your data*/) {

                $nav .= build_menu($items[$i]->children, $currentPage, $depth--);

            } else {
                // regular menu item
                if ($items[$i]->type !== 'custom') {
                    $nav.= '<li class="'.$activeClass.'"><a href="'.get_permalink($items[$i]->object_id).'" target="'.$items[$i]->target.'">'.$items[$i]->title.'</a></li>';
                } else {
                    $nav.= '<li><a href="'.$items[$i]->url.'" target="'.$items[$i]->target.'">'.$items[$i]->title.'</a></li>';
                }
            }
        }
        return '<ul>'.$nav.'</ul>';
    }
}
```

#### Disclaimer

This is untested code to give you an idea of the logic behind it.